# How to change port Number In Hugo static site?

Tags: hugo

we Host a new site in windows machine unable to change port number 1313 to 80 Its possible to change?

Answer (score 3):

See the [official doc](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_server/), you could try to use the `-p` option:

```
$ hugo server -b http://localhost/yoursite -p 80
```